# Way to copy/recover data much larger than any storage medium I have?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a 3 TB LDM Windows partition that was from a Windows 8 install that hibernated and I have since lost the hiberfil.sys or ability to boot into that install (through my own stupid actions, but that's beside the point).

The partition has ~ 1.6 TB of data that I would like to keep and use. The only problem is that I can't figure out a way to mount the partition in readwrite mode, only read-only.

The procedure I used to get it to mount at all was the following:

1. Installed ldmtool
2. `ldmtool create all`
3. Attempted mounting with `mount /dev/mapper/ldm_vol_JDPHENIX-01-Dg0_Volume1 ~/mnt/hdd/`, failed with `The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).`
4. Successfully mounted with `-o ro` as suggested by the error message.

The question is **how do I go about getting the data from this partition to a usable state** (I define as mounted in some storage medium as read-write)?

I had considered purchasing sufficient cloud storage somewhere to temporarily hold the data, but that would exceed my bandwidth cap by a factor of 6.

I do consider "purchase an HDD capable of holding the data" as a valid solution, so if that's the ideal way to do this, don't refrain from posting exactly that.

Edit: 
I chose to purchase a new hard drive. I'm still interested in others' takes on how to best handle this.

Comment: Don't you think repairing the Windows boot would be easier? When your hiberfil.sys is corrupted or gone, but Windows still wants to resume from hibernation, there has to be an option to throw the hibernation data away and perform a clean boot. Maybe you have to hold [Ctrl] or [F6] or [F8] while booting, before it tries to load the hibernation state.

Comment: @ByteCommander The partition storing hiberfil.sys was obliterated by parted. There is no repair for this particular Windows install. (Yes, it would definitely be easier if an option)

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the best thing for me to do, in my circumstance, was to purchase a new HDD large enough for what I needed.

It ends up being more cost effective than a temporary cloud solution or purchasing a BD-R drive and media, and worth avoiding the frustration of USB thumb sticks and DVD-Rs, plus I can get more utility out of it later.